# Scala SortedSet - sorted by one Ordering and unique by something else?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Say I have a set of Strings that I want to be ordered by length but unique by the normal `String` uniqueness. What I mean is that I that I could have more than one String of same length in the `Set`, but that they should be sorted by length.

I want to express the ordering like this:

```
val orderByLength = Ordering[Int].on[String](_ length)
```

which I think looks really nice. But if I were to throw this into a SortedSet, say like this:

```
scala> val s = SortedSet("foo", "bar")(orderByLength)
s: scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet[java.lang.String] = TreeSet(bar)
```

I only get 'bar'. This is because the `Ordering` represents a total ordering and so when `compare` returns 0 the elements are considered identical.

Therefore I'm thinking I need to make a chained ordering and compare the Strings if the lengths are equal. To do this I used the "pimp my library"-pattern like this:

```
trait ChainableOrderings {
  class ChainableOrdering[T](val outer: Ordering[T]) {
    def ifEqual(next: Ordering[T]): Ordering[T] = new Ordering[T] {
      def compare(t1: T, t2: T) = {
        val first = outer.compare(t1, t2)
        if (first != 0) first else next.compare(t1, t2)
      }
    }
  }
  implicit def chainOrdering[T](o: Ordering[T]) = new ChainableOrdering[T](o)
}
```

That I can use like:

```
val ordering = Ordering[Int].on[String](_ length) ifEqual Ordering[String]
```

I thought it looked really great, but then I realized that what I wanted to do was not really to order by the natural ordering of Strings, I just wanted ordering by size, but uniqueness by something else. Is this possible in a more elegant way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What I do in such situations is this:

```
val orderByLength = Ordering[(Int, String)].on[String](s => s.length -> s)
```

In other words, use a tuple to get a tie-breaker.

On the other hand, I think it's silly of `SortedSet` to consider elements the same based on their *ordering*. I think this has been discussed before, but I wouldn't discard the possibility of searching mailing lists archives and the scala trac for discussions/tickets on this, and maybe trying to get `SortedSet` to change its behavior.

Comment: A set only contains distinct objects.  A sorted set has a total ordering.  In particular, `S contains a` and `S contains b` means that either `a<b` or `b<a` or `a eq b`.  Are you suggesting that `SortedSet` have some sort of partial ordering (e.g. a total ordering on equivalence classes instead of on items)?

Comment: Excellent! That's a whole lot more concise than my version.

Comment: @rex Maybe it would be useful with a preordered set (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder). Say a redblack tree for the provided `Ordering` with leafs of `HashSets` for the natural ordering/equivalence of the type. At least my intuition was that the provided `Ordering` would only be used for sorting and not to look for equivalence, I don't know why.

Comment: @hedefalk - Indeed, I should have said "some sort of preordering", since even partial orderings have the equivalence property.  However, a preordering alone is too weak, since it admits that elements may be incomparable.  In contrast, in this case, we seem to want the order relationship for every pair of elements to be defined, but for equivalence classes of order to be perfectly okay (`a<b` and `b<a` both false, but subject to the requirement that if neither `a` nor `b` is less than the other and neither `a` nor `c` is less than the other, then neither `b` nor `c` is less than the other).

Comment: Interesting. `java.util.TreeSet`, if you construct it with a Comparator using string length, works the same way as Scala `SortedSet` (it only keeps one element with a given length). The `Comparator` docs explain why: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html.  I have to agree with Daniel though, intuitively you would think that set membership is separate from ordering.