# Sorted collection of orders in Scala

Tags: scala, sorting, scala-collections

I need to maintain a sorted collection of orders of the form...

```
Order(id: Long, price: Long, quantity: Long)
```

...where `order.price` is the variable on which the order of the collection is defined. I also need to look up an `order` by `order.id` and remove it from the collection.

I initially tried `mutable.PriorityQueue`, but could not figure out how to look up and remove orders.  I then moved to `immutable.TreeSet`, but `TreeSet` considers orders with the same price `duplicates` and drops one of them.  I had thought about using `immutable.TreeMap` but that collection sorts keys and the natural keys for my orders is `id` not `price`.

What collection should I use?  The ideal collection would seem to be a Map where the sort order is defined over keys.  As far as I can tell, this doesn't exist.

Comment: I guess the issue arises because you want to sort the set based on one thing, and test for equality based on another. This has been tacked previously here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952374/scala-sortedset-sorted-by-one-ordering-and-unique-by-something-else

Comment: @TillRohrmann Yes id will be unique.

Comment: @melps Exactly. I incorrectly assumed that set equality would be determined independently of the `compare` method.

Comment: @melps It seems that the issue is that I need to define a total ordering over my order objects.  Since my id values will be unique, I can define a total ordering over `(id, price)` tuples and then use `TreeSet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is no collection that does exactly what you mention.

You might be able to inherit from java's [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). It keeps items accessible by key but keep a linked list of the internal nodes to have a stable ordering. That implementation uses insertion order (most efficient since you just append to the underlying linked list), but you could customize it to do insertions on the liked list based on a custom Comparator (so insertion would be O(n)). Hope it helps!