# Sorted Scala collection with duplicates

Tags: scala, sorting, collections

I'm looking for a data structure in Scala which allows me to keep a collection sorted by a criteria, but allow duplicates of that criteria. The best example could be people. They could be sorted by age and obviously, two with the same age are not necessary the same people. This has been asked some time ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802216/sorted-collection-of-orders-in-scala), but I couldn't get a solution. I've tested mostly of the regular sorted structures and the recommended PriorityQueue, which does not grant a global ordering, so I can't use it. Is there some update in this situation or still the same than the cuoted question?

Note: I can't consider sorting some regular structure after modifications because these are very frequent and require the collection to be in a sorted state

Comment: How are you items defined? Can you show some code? Are they `case class`? I'm asking because for your example, I would expect two people to have an attribute to differentiate them like a name or id.

Comment: I'm not sure your example is well-suited. If I wanted to avoid duplicates, I would probably make sure that my data model contains enough information to make sure that two objects represent two different values. `case class Person(age: Int)` might lend itself to spurious duplicates but that's way less likely with `case class Person(uuid: UUID, age: Int)`, which would allow me to sort unique persons by their age using a regular `SortedSet`. If this is not something that applies to your case, I would recommend following @GaëlJ's advice above and describing your data model.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "global ordering" and why you think `PriorityQueue` does not "grant" it. PriorityQueue seems like your best choice if you are looking O(1) inserts. Or use `SortedSet` as suggested above. What specifically is it that you are you going to _do_ with the collection you are looking for? Share some code showing how you plan on using it.

Comment: What kind of duplication do you need? Because you can use e.g. `SortedMap` if you want to gather different element under the same key, and use that property as the key. But if you have a several different entities, I'd rather sort by all of them and use SortedSet than sort by one property and then tackle the issue of distinct values treated as the same - the later requires a hacky solution for a problem that it created itself. E.g. `implicit val peopleOrder = Ordering.by(p: People => p.age).orElseBy(_.uuid)` and then `SortedSet[People]` would not deduplicate if age is the same but uuid isn't

Comment: @Dima I mean that when I traverse a PriorityQueue all elements aren't ordered. From my own testing I got, for example, persons "ordered" by age like this: 30, 30, 27, 20, 20, 25. Also did some research about max heaps (how PriorityQueue is implemented) and found that indeed all elements won't be sorted

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok that worked for me, thx. Did not gave more context or examples cause the real use case is a post evaluation for a genetic algorithm where the elements must be ordered according to a metric and two or more can have the same. I was still on design step and thus there's no code for that

Comment: @xandor19 no idea what "research" you found. If elements you retrieve from PriorityQueue are out of order, that must be a bug. If you can reproduce it reliably, you should create an issue. The _entire point_ of PriorityQueue is that you retrieve element in order.

Comment: `PriorityQueue` spits elements in order, internally it can store a tree which conforms to a heap property, so its not a linear structure like List or Vector, but on `pop` it always removes the least element, so "pop until its empty" will create a "global order". However to use any ordered data structure one have to be aware that: partial ordering (including total ordering) should preserve antisymmetric property: `a <= b && b <= a` iff `a == b`. You cannot complain that you deduplicated elements with a `compare` if the comparison ignored properties used for an equality check.

Comment: You can use some library to generate `scala.numeric.Ordering` or `cats.Order` out of all attributes of a case class if needed.

Answer (score 0):

From all comments and the other cited post, the solution that worked for me was to chain orderings. Something like:

```
val ordering: Ordering[T] = Ordering
.by[T](/*your criteria*/)
.orElseBy(/*tie breaker criteria*/)
```

Note that this does not guarantee that full duplicates will be kept. There could be as many chained criterias as need also.